# SQL AS statement without column name shortcut

Tags: sql, sql-server

what does the `AS` in a statement such as below do?

`SELECT column AS
FROM table`

Since there is no shortcut, does it even do anything?

Comment: did you try it? That probably give you an error.

Comment: In this context, 'AS' should be used to assign an alias to a column.  This syntax will not execute without error until you provide the alias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tag your actual RDBMS, the following is valid for SQL-Server, but you'll be able to transfer this to your system:

--A dummy table as declared table variable

```
DECLARE @DummyTbl TABLE(SomeColumn INT);
INSERT INTO @DummyTbl VALUES(1),(2),(3);
```

--Variation of namings

```
SELECT SomeColumn               --The orginal name
      ,SomeColumn AS OtherName  --A classical alias
      ,SomeColumn test          --The alias does NOT need the 'AS' 
      ,SomeColumn [AS]          --You may name your output 'AS'
FROM @DummyTbl;
```

But your syntax is - at least with SQL Server - not valid. `AS` is - in this context - a reserved word.